# ASP.Net httpwebrequest not posting request body

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

My hands are up in the air - I cry, Uncle.  Help me understand:

I wrote a simple HttpWebRequest posting to a clients' https://website.
It has specific header requirements and a JSON request body.  The GetResponseStream, after receiving a GetResponse StatusCode.OK, is an error provided by their server.  They checked their logs and said while the headers were present, the request Body was ".

Here is my code:

```
    public const string API_URILogin = "https://dev.clientURL.com/test/api/login";
    private void RequestTest()
    {
        LoginAPIStruct loginInfo = new LoginAPIStruct();

        loginInfo.loginId = TestId;
        loginInfo.password = TestPw;
        loginInfo.vehicleType = "E";
        loginInfo.deviceId = "ABCDEF";
        loginInfo.clientId = "123456";
        loginInfo.appVersion = string.Empty;
        loginInfo.osType = string.Empty;
        loginInfo.osVersion = string.Empty;

        // Call LoginAPI
        string loginStatus = LoginAPI(loginInfo);
        //Display Results
        lblResults.Text = loginStatus;
    }


    // Public Variables
    public static string errorMessage;

    // ** Client Login **
    public static string LoginAPI(LoginAPIStruct loginInfo)
    {
        // Post Login to Client.  Get response with Vehicle structure.  
        string loginInfoSerialized = string.Empty;
        string returnString = string.Empty;

        loginInfoSerialized = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(loginInfo);

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(API_URILogin);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Headers.Add("From", "CC");
        request.Headers.Add("Language", "0");
        request.Headers.Add("Offset", "-8");
        request.Headers.Add("To", "CCM");

        // Post Request
        using (StreamWriter streamPost = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            streamPost.Write(loginInfoSerialized);
        }

        // Get Response
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            // Status Okay.
            //string responseStatusDescription = response.StatusDescription;

            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                try
                {
                    var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

                    returnString = result;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    returnString = ex.Message;
                }

            }
        }
        else
        {
            returnString = response.StatusCode.ToString();
        }

        return returnString;
    }   // end LoginAPI
```

My JSON string appears to be valid - I paste it into Fiddler, along with setting the headers, and Fiddler returns a successful login.

From ASP.Net, it returns their documented error that the email address (loginId) is required.    I don't see anything incorrect in my C# code.  Any ideas where else to look?  Could the client have something on their hosting site that blocks or filters out a certain request?  I'm stuck.

Comment: Update:  I found how to configure ASP.net to have Fiddler  act as proxy.            GlobalProxySelection.Select = new WebProxy("127.0.0.1", 8888);

I see my headers, but the Content-Length is set to 0 and no content is being sent.  WHY?

Answer (score 0):

So, for anyone who cares to know.... you must "close" the StreamWriter after performing the .Write(payload) command, otherwise it doesn't actually send the data.

```
    // Post Request
        StreamWriter streamPost = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream());
        streamPost.Write(loginInfoSerialized);
        streamPost.Close();    //Don't forget to Close() or no data sent!!
```

I hope this helps someone else as I spend two weeks fighting this omission.  Ciao.

Comment: Instead of manually closing stream, use `using` statement as StreamWriter implements IDisposable interface which automatically dispose the stream as soon as your program goes out of `using` statement

Answer (score 0):

i will do post like this:

```
ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
byte[] byte1 = encoding.GetBytes(loginInfoSerialized);

request.ContentType = "application/json";
request.ContentLength = byte1.Length;
Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream();
stream.Write(byte1, 0, byte1.Length);
stream.Close();
```